# xslt xpath finding all element values of a node in xpath query

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

This question is related with this question [xslt xpath using element values in xpath query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136173/xslt-xpath-using-element-values-in-xpath-query/32137103#32137103) however, the xslt is only for two element nodes HAS TAXONOMIC LEVEL and IS USED AS.

Please find the following xmls:

```
<root>
 <html>
  <table class=" table search-results-property-table">  
                 ....
   <tr>
    <td>
     <span class="versal">HAS TAXONOMIC LEVEL</span>
    </td>
    <td>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a class="versal" href="../../../agrovoc/en/page/c_11125">genus</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <span class="versal">IS USED AS</span>
    </td>
    <td>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a class="versal" href="../../../agrovoc/en/page/c_1591">christmas trees</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a class="versal" href="../../../agrovoc/en/page/c_7776">timber trees</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </td>
   </tr>
    ....
  <table>
 </html>
 <html>
     .....      
   <tr>
    <td>
     <span class="versal">ANOTHER HEADING LABEL</span>
    </td>
    <td>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <p>values</p>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </td>
   </tr>
       ....
 </html>
 <html>
   [third data set...]
    ...
 </html>    
<root>
```

I want to have the element values HAS TAXONOMIC LEVEL, IS USED AS and other LABELS in /tr/td/span[@class='versal] be used in xpath. Next is to output their values (e.g. HAS TAXONOMIC LEVEL) and then get the values of the descendant "a" or "p" of sibling "td" /ul/li/a -> genus under HAS TAXONOMIC LEVEL and christmas trees and timber trees under IS USED AS. And lastly, get the @href if it's available. So I get the following:

```
START HERE
=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500
     ....
=305  \\$aHAS TAXONOMIC LEVEL$bgenus$cc_11125
=305  \\$aIS USED AS$bchrismas trees$cc_1591
=305  \\$aIS USED AS$btimber trees$cc_7776

START HERE
=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500
      ....
=305  \\$aLABEL$bvalue

START HERE
=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500
  (third data set and so on..)
```

Please take note that I have more than one document in this file with xml format like below:

```
<root>
 <html>
   [DATA SET 1]
         ....
 </html>
      <html>
   [DATA SET 2]
         ....
 </html>
       .....
</root>
```

I have the following existing xslt to fit it in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

 <xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:for-each select="html">
  <xsl:text>START HERE</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="table/prefterm" />
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>   
  <xsl:apply-templates select="table/tr/td/span" />
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>   
       ....
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks and cheers!

UPDATE2:
With the following xslt below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

 <xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:for-each select="html">
  <xsl:text>START HERE</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="table/prefterm" />
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>   
  <xsl:apply-templates select="table/tr/td/span" />
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>   
  <xsl:apply-templates select="table/tr"/>
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
       .......
 <xsl:template match="table/tr">
  <xsl:for-each select="../tr[td/span/@class='versal']">
   <xsl:variable name="span" select="td/span" />
   <xsl:for-each select="td/ul/li/a">
   <xsl:text>=305  \\$a</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="$span"/>
   <xsl:text>$c</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each> 
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this template I'm getting many values repeated several times that is seem is based on the number of another node like below:

```
START HERE
=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500    
 .....
=305  \\$aHAS TAXONOMIC LEVEL$cgenus
=305  \\$aIS USED AS$cchristmas trees
=305  \\$aIS USED AS$ctimber trees
=305  \\$aHAS TAXONOMIC LEVEL$cgenus
=305  \\$aIS USED AS$cchristmas trees
=305  \\$aIS USED AS$ctimber trees

START HERE
=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500    
 ..... set 2 and also =305 is printed many times
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the previous question, the expression give is this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="html/table/tr[td/span='HAS TAXONOMIC LEVEL' or td/span='IS USED AS']">
```

If you want to include other values, change it to this...

```
 <xsl:for-each select="html/table/tr[td/span/@class='versal']">
```

Looking at your output though, it looks like you want a new section for each `html` element, so might put the code in a template that matches `html`. Something like this...

```
<xsl:template match="html">
    <xsl:text>START HERE</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="table/tr[td/span/@class='versal']">
        <!-- Existing code -->
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: To fit it into your (second) XSLT, try this instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

 <xsl:template match="root">
   <xsl:for-each select="html">
     <xsl:text>START HERE</xsl:text>
     <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:text>=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500</xsl:text>
     <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:for-each select="table/tr[td/span/@class='versal']">
       <xsl:variable name="span" select="td/span" />
       <xsl:for-each select="td/ul/li/a">
         <xsl:text>=305  \\$a</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="$span"/>
         <xsl:text>$c</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:for-each> 
   </xsl:for-each> 
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The main problem in your existing XSLT is that you do `<xsl:for-each select="//table/tr[td/span/@class='versal']">`, but the `//table` will get all tables in the document, so you lose context. You need to do just `<xsl:for-each select="table/tr[td/span/@class='versal']">`

Comment: Hi! I actually have this existing xslts: <xsl:template match="root">
   <xsl:for-each select="html">
 <xsl:text>START HERE</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="table/prefterm" />
 <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text> 
 <xsl:apply-templates select="table/tr/td/span" />
 <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text> 
 <xsl:apply-templates select="table/tr"/>
 <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text> I'll try to fit it in.

Comment: @schnydszch I've included a full XSLT sample in my answer, if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Tim C. you're answer fits really well resolving my problem, and also I learned that I can have xsl:for-each inside xsl:for-each in my first template (template match="root"). That's why I was losing context.